# netbeans zend create action error

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, controller, action

I am using Zend Framework with NetBeans. I can create controllor, an action for IndexController, but I can't create actions for new controllers.
When I do create action it says that controller was not found.
What should I do?

Comment: How do you create those actions?

Comment: In NetBeans I use Run Zend command... or something like that with command: create action someAction someController.

Comment: When you try to add new action, is your controller already exists?

Comment: Of course. I can add an action to index controller, but I can`t do that with ang added by myself.

Comment: Are you in the root directory of application when invoking zf create action newaction NewController?

Comment: The problem is that .zfproject isn't being updated. I need to add controller there manually. :)

Comment: I think NetBeans option to create action is just wrapper on the zf. Then the only solution is adding action manually in your controller file. It's just a method with name finishing as "Action". Isn't it OK for you?